# Caliburn Micro how to auto-close Conductor with no children

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a MainComm VM which creates a window MainChatWindow VM, the MainChatWindowVM is a conductor.OneActive and contains a tab control, where each tab is a dynamically added ChatTabVM. Once the last chat conversation is closed, the MainChatWindow VM conductor contains no more Items, and **I need to somehow trigger the mainchatwindow window to close since there are no more tabs.** Here is how my program is structured (which by the way I have a feeling is not very correct):

```
public class MainCommViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<RosterEvent>, IHandle<PrivateMessageEvent> //changed from Screen
{

    public MainCommViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IWindowManager windowManager, MainChatWindowViewModel mainChatWindowViewModel)
    {
        WindowManager = windowManager;
        MainChatWindowViewModel = mainChatWindowViewModel;
        conversationList = new Dictionary<string, ChatTabViewModel>();
        //...
    }

    public void Handle(PrivateMessageEvent message)
    {

        if (!MainChatWindowViewModel.IsActive)
        {
            dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
            settings.Title = "test title";
            WindowManager.ShowWindow(MainChatWindowViewModel, null, settings);
        }
        else
        {
            if(MainChatWindowViewModel.Items.Count == 0) //if there are no tabs, and the screen is active
            {
                MainChatWindowViewModel.Focus(); //then focus the window so they can see the newly added msg from below
            }
        }

        //Does tab already exist for this user/conversation?
        if (conversationList.ContainsKey(message.Pm.userId.User))
        {
            //Tab for user/conversation already exists
            ChatTabViewModel chatTabViewModel = conversationList[message.Pm.userId.User];
            chatTabViewModel.DisplayName = message.Pm.userId.User;
            chatTabViewModel.Conversation.chatMessages.Add(message.Pm);
        }
        else
        {
            ChatTabViewModel ctvm = new ChatTabViewModel(message.Pm.userId);
            ctvm.DisplayName = message.Pm.userId.User;

            ctvm.Conversation.chatMessages.Add(message.Pm);

            conversationList.Add(message.Pm.userId.User, ctvm);

            ctvm.Deactivated += new EventHandler<DeactivationEventArgs>(ChildTab_Deactivated);

            MainChatWindowViewModel.ActivateItem(ctvm);

        }

    }
    void ChildTab_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivationEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctvm = sender as ChatTabViewModel;
        if(ctvm != null)
        {
            if (e.WasClosed)
            {
                conversationList.Remove(ctvm.Conversation.User.User); //this users chat tab was closed, remove it from list
                //cant TryClose() here to close window if tab count = 0

            }

        }
```

and MainChatWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainChatWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainChatWindowViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IWindowManager WindowManager)
    {
        events.Subscribe(this);

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

MainChatWindowView.xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="417" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                <Button Content="X"
                        cal:Message.Attach="DeactivateItem($dataContext, 'true')" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

ChatTabViewModel:

```
public class ChatTabViewModel : Screen
{
    private Conversation conversation;
    public ChatTabViewModel(JID user)
    {
        conversation = new Conversation();
        conversation.User = user;

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

As you can see, MainChatWindowView.xaml defines an X button for each tab, which when clicked calls the MainChatWindowViewModel conductors DeactivateItem for that tabViewModel, and closes the tab. 
**My issue: once all the tabs are gone, I'm not sure how to signal the window to close itself.** Hopefully I'm not missing something obvious, but I've gone over a whole bunch of functions, events, and overrides trying to make it work in my situation.. should I restructure this?

Comment: http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition and specifically referencing the ICloseStrategy near the bottom of the page is probably what you need to look at.  nb: example is in Silverlight. So a window closing event would need to be handled.

Comment: I looked into it, it seems the CloseStrategy is only used when the window is already closing. I've tried a few hacks like catching the tab VM's deactivated event and trying to tryClose() the window VM, but that didn't work. Also tried catching the Items_collectionchanged, but its too early to kill the window at that point.. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: EventAggregator would possibly be of use in this case where you know to send a message to signal when you have no more chat screens, trigger the auto-close with the handling of the event message.  if(conversationList.Count == 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exhausted all of Caliburn Micro's features to do this automatically, and I don't think such a thing exists. That being said, there is an obvious and simple way to handle this issue by replacing the deactivate call on tab close, like so:

Add this function to MainChatWindowViewModel.cs

```
    public void DeactivateItemAndTryClose(IScreen item, bool close)
    {
        DeactivateItem(item, close);
        if(this.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            this.TryClose(); //No more tabs open, close window.
        }

    }
```

Update MainChatWindowView.xaml TabControl like so:

```
        <TabControl x:Name="Items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="417" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    <Button Content="X"
                            cal:Message.Attach="DeactivateItemAndTryClose($dataContext, 'true')" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```